# Is there such a phrase as "show them to the house"?

Tags: prepositions

I was asked a question in my Language exam:
Alex was asked to show the guests_________the house.

I have found one solution to be around from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show%20%28someone%29%20around) but could not find any reference to the usage of *to*.

What could be the other possible answers to this and is "*to* the house" correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any context for the sentence? I think that _around_ is more likely than _to_.

Comment: There is no context to this sentence. It was just a practice question that I came across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SOED can be got the following definitions.

> **show** **11 b** Guide (or lead) a person, *to*, *into*, *over*, or *through*, a place, house, etc. [since] Late Middle English.

> **show round** show (a person) over a place, show the sights to.

"To the house" is correct according to the Oxford dictionary. However,the phrasal verb  "*show sb around/round (sth)* is used more commonly; it can be taken as synonym when used with "through".

> **show around** phrasal verb
> show somebody around (something)
> (British English also show somebody round (something))
> ​to be a guide for somebody when they visit a place for the first time to show them >what is interesting
> ♦ We were shown around the school by one of the students.

These ngrams  shows that the form using "around" is more common: ([ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=show+him+around+the+house%2Cshow+him+to+the+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshow%20him%20around%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshow%20him%20to%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshow%20him%20around%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshow%20him%20to%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0), [ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=show+her+around+the+house%2Cshow+her+to+the+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshow%20her%20around%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0)). I suspect that "show sb to (a place)" is more formal.

Comment: "To" and "around" are not synonyms here. A porter in a hotel "shows you *to* your room" (while carrying your luggage there) but does not "show you *around* your room" (unless you are staying in a multi-room suite in a very expensive hotel).

Comment: @alephzero I agree with that, only "through" would do.